# Samsung Curved Monitor Distorted Display

Tags: display, hdmi, external-display, brightness, fullscreen

This new 24 inch curved monitor works just fine when I checked it by connecting with my laptop, but whenever I connect it to my old custom built PC, the screen dims randomly, goes dark and flickers between dimness & brightness and shows moving horizontal black lines and sometimes the screen blackens completely for a long time with like 5% brightness barely to shut my PC down. 
With my laptop, I witnessed full optimal brightness but not seeing it with my custom built PC now (I saw it lit up bright in the first couple of days though).

It worked perfectly well for the first couple of days but after that this problem started. 
Also when I connect it with HDMI cable to the HDMI port in my graphics card, it doesn't detects it but the system starts. Should I try HDMI 2.0? Will it be a sure shot option or is it some hardware fault in my system?

Thirdly, the resolution of my monitor is 1920x1080 but my Windows 7 shows the maximum resolution as 1600x1200. How can I get maximum resolution here?
Quality-wise some HD content looks a little grainy.

To sum up, my monitor has the following issues :

Random dimming of screen and brightness issue

HDMI

Maximum Resolution

I tried cleaning the dust and also unplugged & plugged some connections in my system but no luck.

Please tell me what's causing these problems and help me solve them ASAP.

Thanks, I'd really appreciate your help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Check the Resolution and the Refresh Rate to
  ensure it matches the native resolution of the TV
- Update the TV firmware to the latest version, which is reported to work
  by some sources
- Check for a display driver update on the manufacturer's website for the computer

Otherwise, there were some claims to workarounds:

- Set the TV to an input with no video source prior to shutdown
- Hold the power button down on the Samsung remote until the TV turns off
  and back on again

Comment: harrymc, your answer doesn't helps.

Comment: There have been very many reports about this problem with this TV. I have summarized what users did say that solved this same problem. Did you try any of them?

Comment: harrymc I am not asking about TV, I'm asking solutions for my samsung curved monitor if you can read thoroughly, and no I didn't find anything related to that here.

Comment: TV and monitor are synonyms here. You shouldn't dismiss this without checking the ones that apply to your device. But if you demand, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Ok, I don't think it's the firmware of my monitor cause it works well on laptop as a 2nd screen, neither the remote cause I haven't got any! The mentioned resolution I can't find, but it's still the most optimal one for now, refresh rate sits at 60. I updated the driver but it's still a little dim now, with no constant flickers though.

Comment: We have some improvement. There might be some adjustments possible on the monitor's on-screen menu. Also on the computer (Windows?).

Comment: Well guess what, the flickers are back, and my screen wanders between dimness and brightness again and again! I need a better solution.

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't hardware, either the monitor or the display adapter?

Comment: Monitor is fine cause it works on laptop like I keep repeating. So it's the hardware inside my system that's faulty. Maybe my video card or RAM or something else that I can't seem to find out. I've also updated the drivers of my video card & also reseated it but no luck till now.

Comment: Check well the specifications of the adapter vs. monitor. Many times such problems are because the frequency of the display adapter exceeds that of the monitor.

Comment: My 1GB DDR5 video card is like 7-8yrs old, and hence it shouldn't exceed any new monitor frequency as it allows 60Hz on both. Tell me something that we're badly missing here.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a new video card?

Comment: Nope. Something is at fault and IDK what. That's it.